# Generate pattern inside polygon in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, polygon, leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet and mapping. I'm currently looking for solutions to how I can autogenerate a line pattern inside a polygon drawn on the map with a pre defined distance between each line.

Does anyone have any suggestion to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

This [Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern) lets you do exactly that:

> **Leaflet.pattern**
>   Provides the ability to use SVG patterns as backgrounds for Leaflet Paths.

Options include:

- X Offset
- Y Offset
- Width
- Height
- Angle

From the [stripe pattern example](https://teastman.github.io/Leaflet.pattern/pattern-stripes.html):

[image]